# Given a number, how to get the previous and next value inside a list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
VALUE_TO_FIND  UNORDERED_LIST
5              [0,10]
3              [1,0,10,8,4,2]
2              [9,10,0]
5              [4,8,0,1,2,10]
4              [0,10,4]
```

Given the value from column `VALUE_TO_FIND`, how can I get the previous and next value inside `UNORDERED_LIST`?

```
VALUE_TO_FIND  UNORDERED_LIST   PREVIOUS_VALUE   NEXT_VALUE
5              [0,10]           0                10
3              [1,0,10,8,4,2]   2                4
2              [9,10,0]         0                9
5              [4,8,0,1,2,10]   4                8
4              [0,10,4]         4                4
```

Note: `UNORDERED_LIST` will always have the min and max of `VALUE_TO_FIND`

Comment: What do you mean by "previous" and "next"? What is the rule that tells you these desired outputs?

Comment: I edit the question. What I need is to get the closest value from column VALUE_TO_FIND , both above and below inside the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a more efficient solution, but I have tried `zip`ping the two relevant columns:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'VALUE_TO_FIND': [5, 3, 2, 5, 4,],
    'UNORDERED_LIST': [[0,10], [1,0,10,8,4,2], [9,10,0], [4,8,0,1,2,10], [0,10,4],]})

def find_prev_next(x, lst):
    return max(y for y in lst if y <= x), min(y for y in lst if y >= x) # tuple

_ = [find_prev_next(x, lst) for x, lst in zip(df.VALUE_TO_FIND, df.UNORDERED_LIST)]
df['PREVIOUS_VALUE'], df['NEXT_VALUE'] = zip(*_)

print(df)
   # VALUE_TO_FIND       UNORDERED_LIST  PREVIOUS_VALUE  NEXT_VALUE
# 0              5              [0, 10]               0          10
# 1              3  [1, 0, 10, 8, 4, 2]               2           4
# 2              2           [9, 10, 0]               0           9
# 3              5  [4, 8, 0, 1, 2, 10]               4           8
# 4              4           [0, 10, 4]               4           4
```